# GIT: how to force a merge commit to an ancestor

Tags: git, merge, commit

In GIT, I have two branches and two commits:

```
 A(master)---B(branch "topic")
```

- the HEAD of the branch 'master' is commit A
- the HEAD of the branch 'topic'  is commit B
- commit A is the parent of commit B

I would like to create a merge commit C in the "topic" branch (it would have A and B as parents). (I know that this seems odd, and that the merge commit would be empty.)

```
 A(master)---B---C (branch "topic")
  \-------------/
```

I managed to create this merge commit in a too complex way (see below). Is there any easier way to create this merge commit?

Thanks for your answers!

---

Initial state:

```
$ git init plop
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/plop/.git/
$ cd plop/
$ git commit -m "Initial commit (commit A)"  --allow-empty
[master (root-commit) a687d4e] Initial commit (commit A)
$ git checkout -b topic
Switched to a new branch 'topic'
$ git commit -m "Some work on my topic branch (commit B)" --allow-empty
[topic d4d1c71] Some work on my topic branch (commit B)
$ #OK, we now reached the initial state
```

---

Some tries:

```
$ git merge master #Does not work
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge --no-ff -s ours master #Does not work
Already up-to-date.
```

---

Is there an easier way to achieve the following?

```
$ #Let's try another way (too complex!)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge --no-ff topic
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by recursive.
$ git checkout topic
Switched to branch 'topic'
$ git merge master
Updating d4d1c71..641e7ae
Fast-forward
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git reset --hard HEAD^1
HEAD is now at a687d4e Initial commit
$ git checkout topic
Switched to branch 'topic'
$ git log #This is what I wanted to reach
commit 641e7aeb614d9b49796e8f11abd3a0290ac08b40
Merge: a687d4e d4d1c71
Author: xxx <yyy.zzz>
Date:   Sat Jul 23 12:52:41 2011 +0200

    Merge branch 'topic'

commit d4d1c71c87b94335c8852ab7675cbb663965ef7d
Author: xxx <yyy.zzz>
Date:   Sat Jul 23 12:50:11 2011 +0200

    Some work on my topic branch (commit B)

commit a687d4eb88b9f6d661122a5766dd632dd462fbaa
Author: xxx <yyy.zzz>
Date:   Sat Jul 23 12:49:52 2011 +0200

    Initial commit (commit A)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It doesn't make sense. Creating a new commit on `master` that would merge in `topic` would be possible (and it also makes some sense).

Comment: Here’s a possible use case for merging in ancestor commits: imagine the branch contains some changes to a file (e. g. it’s some sort of downstream branch) that we now want to revert. Doing a simple `git revert` makes `git blame` after that attribute all reverted lines to the revert commit, but it would be rather more helpful to have them attributed to the upstream. Making a revert commit and marking it as a merge with the upstream achieves this.

Comment: good question. here's an example of why you'd want to do that, for everyone asking "WHY". I have a `gh-pages` branch, which has built docs, and dist/prod files that are checked-in only on that branch, meant for deployment. My `dev` branch was ahead of `master`, and I merged `dev -> gh-pages` and rebuilt, then deployed. but then I realized I F'd up because I want my master build to be deployed, not my development build. So I `checkout gh-pages` and attempted `merge --no-commit master` but it alerts *"Already up-to-date."* Forcing a downstream (empty) merge would be helpful in this situation.

Comment: just hit this problem, master was just merged into topic, and I want another commit when topic is merged into master... but hitting this problem.
This is important for tools, which need to know which merge ancestor to follow.
Also it does not help when git log --graph displays your master on the right or in the middle of topic branches.

Comment: Here’s another use case: copying files while (again) preserving `git blame` output without requiring non-default `blame -CC` options. Rename the file, then merge it back in. (Don’t you love it when you come back to Stack Overflow via Google and see you’ve already upvoted and commented on the question?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPD**: Cleaner way to do same thing without messing with sha1 directly:

```
$ echo "merge commit" | git commit-tree topic^{tree} -p master -p topic
4201b6abae6bb06f929ea00fbc35019679d55535

$ git merge 4201b6abae6bb06f929ea00fbc35019679d55535
Updating b826a8e..4201b6a
Fast-forward
```

Or even one-line command:

```
$ git merge $(echo "merge commit" | git commit-tree topic^{tree} -p master -p topic)
```

For details of what that's doing - read entire answer :)

---

I'm totally agree with others in that it has no sense for me, but if you really want it - it is possible with low-level plumbing commands as described below.

First of all, you should know sha1 of your parent commits. I suppose B has comment 'change from topic', A has comment 'change from master' and we're currently at B (topic branch).

```
$ git log --format=oneline -2
b826a8e93ac8da0de5bfb5b70d5f4e7c352a01fa change from topic
8b7653a529fb3ce964fda79bfd57e645441ad893 change from master
```

Then you should know sha1 of concrete tree object of commit B:

```
$ git cat-file -p topic
tree 867f31c455a371756ec353b54d755f51d98d62c4
parent 8b7653a529fb3ce964fda79bfd57e645441ad893
author ivan-danilov <email@gmail.com> 1311518908 +0300
committer ivan-danilov <email@gmail.com> 1311518908 +0300

change from topic
```

So it is `867f31c455a371756ec353b54d755f51d98d62c4`. And finally you should execute [`git-commit-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html) command:

```
$ echo "merge commit" | git commit-tree 867f31c455a371756ec353b54d755f51d98d62c4 -p b826a8e93ac8da0de5bfb5b70d5f4e7c352a01fa -p 8b7653a529fb3ce964fda79bfd57e645441ad893
4201b6abae6bb06f929ea00fbc35019679d55535
```

Note that I used pipeline redirection as `git-commit-tree` takes commit comment from `stdin` stream. First param is tree's sha1 we got with `git cat-file` and two others are commits' sha1 we got with `git log`.

Output from command is the sha1 of newly created merge commit. Now you want to fast-forward topic branch to it:

```
$ git merge 4201b6abae6bb06f929ea00fbc35019679d55535
Updating b826a8e..4201b6a
Fast-forward
```

That's all. You have what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, git commit-tree is what I was missing. I agree that I have to reconsider our workflow if it leads to that kind of low level GIT commands...

Comment: @Stefan If done from master - it'd create merge commit in the master branch, which is not what OP wants. IF from topic I execute `git merge master --no-ff` - git replies 'Already up-to-date.'

Comment: Oh right, sry. should have read more carefully, that OP wants to merge the other way round. in that case i'd use (on topic branch): `cur=$(git rev-parse HEAD); git reset master; git merge --no-ff $cur -m 'merge master into topic'`

Comment: I’d recommend swapping the order of the parents, putting the branch as the first parent and master as the second. This is what `git merge` would do if it didn’t refuse to run.

Answer (score 3):

Merging the other way around should work:

```
git branch tmp master    # tmp points to A
git checkout tmp
git merge --no-ff -m 'odd merge' topic    # merge B+A ==> C
git checkout topic
git reset --hard tmp     # topic now points to C
git branch -d tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

It only makes sense to make a merge commit if there's a difference between `master` and `topic` - if they have diverged. In your case, there's nothing to merge - `topic` already has all of `master`'s commits, so git won't allow you to create a merge that does nothing.

It works fine if you have a commit in `master` that's not in `topic`:

```
$ git init plop
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Temp/plop/.git/
$ cd plop
$ git commit -m "Initial commit (commit A)" --allow-empty
[master (root-commit) b6e2e91] Initial commit (commit A)
$ git commit -m "master-only commit (commit C)" --allow-empty
[master 67b491e] master-only commit (commit C)
$ git checkout HEAD~ -b topic
Switched to a new branch 'topic'
$ git commit -m "Some work on my topic branch (commit B)" --allow-empty
[topic 2251f13] Some work on my topic branch (commit B)
$ git merge master
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by recursive.
```

Resulting in...

```
*   592ad46 Merge branch 'master' into topic
|\
| * 67b491e master-only commit (commit C)
* | 2251f13 Some work on my topic branch (commit B)
|/
* b6e2e91 Initial commit (commit A)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I know that it looks strange to require an empty commit, but it would fit in our development workflow (which is maybe broken, that's another question). GIT allows empty commits, so I guess that GIT should not be a problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're on the topic branch, and since it's a direct descendant of master, merging with master makes no sense as topic contains all the changes master has. However, master has none of the changes topic has.

If you checkout master and then merge topic *in to* master, master should fast forward and update its HEAD.

Comment: This is what I did. However, I had to reset the master branch because I do not want its HEAD to move (although I want the HEAD of 'topic' to move). Any easier way to acheive this?

Comment: Oh no. I misunderstood your question. While I don't have an answer, I also don't understand why you want to do this. Maybe telling would help?

Comment: I know that it looks strange to require an empty commit, but it would fit in our development workflow (whis is maybe broken, that's another question). 

GIT allows empty commits, so I guess that GIT should not be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official solution to this problem, there is a workaround. Check out the commit that `master` is on, so that you are in **detached HEAD** state. Then commit an empty commit. Then check out your `topic` branch and merge in that empty commit.

```
$ git checkout 9123456 # (the latest commit on master)
Note: checking out '9123456'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state...
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'empty commit'
[detached HEAD 9123457] empty commit
$ git checkout topic
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind ... 9123457 empty commit
Switched to branch 'topic'
$ git merge 9123457
```